# parsing in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

No matter what I try I keep getting parsing errors and it is extremely frustrating. Any idea what I can do to fix this? 
(This is a function of a tic tac toe program)

```
play' :: Grid -> Player -> IO ()
play' g p 
   | wins O g   = putStrLn "Player O wins!\n " 
   | wins X g   = putStrLn "Player X wins!\n " 
   | full g     = putStrLn "It' s a draw!\n " 
   | p == O     = do i <- getNat (prompt p)
                    case move g i p of 
                       [] -> do putStrLn "ERROR: Invalid move"
                                play' g p 
                       [g'] -> play g' (next p) 
   |p == X      = do putStr "Player X is thinking... " 
                     let gs = bestmoves g p 
                     n <- randomRIO (0, length gs - 1) 
                     play (gs !! n) (next p)
```

Comment: *What* parsing error are you getting?

Comment: You must align the `i` and the `case` in your first `do` block (indent the latter one extra space), the `[]` and `[g']` patterns in your first `case` block (indent the latter two extra spaces), and the `putStrLn` and `play'` statements in your second `do` block (indent the latter three extra spaces).

Comment: keeps giving error on input case (I updated code based on suggestions and still same error)

Comment: Is your parse error not giving you a hint about what line the problem is on?

Comment: yes, sorry. This line: "case move g i p of"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with your indentation. In your "do" blocks, each action needs to start on the same column, like so:

```
example :: IO ()
example = do putStr "How old are you?"
             age <- getLine
             let reply = "You are: " ++ age
             putStr reply
```

Fixing the indentation should allow your code to compile. You just need to shift the 'case move g i p of' line (line 7) one character to the right, so that it lines up with the "i" in the previous line.

Incorrect:

```
   | p == O     = do i <- getNat (prompt p)
                    case move g i p of
```

Correct:

```
   | p == O     = do i <- getNat (prompt p)
                     case move g i p of
```

I made this change locally, and it fixed the issue. The full code with correct indentation follows:

```
play' :: Grid -> Player -> IO ()
play' g p 
   | wins O g   = putStrLn "Player O wins!\n " 
   | wins X g   = putStrLn "Player X wins!\n " 
   | full g     = putStrLn "It' s a draw!\n " 
   | p == O     = do i <- getNat (prompt p)
                     case move g i p of 
                        [] -> do putStrLn "ERROR: Invalid move";
                                 play' g p
                        [g'] -> play g' (next p) 
   |p == X      = do putStr "Player X is thinking... " 
                     let gs = bestmoves g p 
                     n <- randomRIO (0, length gs - 1) 
                     play (gs !! n) (next p)
```

Comment: this worked. Thank you =)

Comment: @whatscsce Happy to help! If this answer or any other one has solved your issue, please consider voting on it or [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419).